# How to delete DataFrame row in Pandas so that it does not show up in Visualiztions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to create a barplot. The problem is that I only want the data of male and female. However, since the 'member_gender' column has 3 values - male, female, other, it shows the other column as well without any bar. and the code for the same is as follows:

df is the main data frame from where I want these 3 columns

```
df_ride_dist = df[['member_gender','user_type','dist_in_km']]
```

Since I want only male and female data, I tried this:

```
df_ride_dist = df_ride_dist.loc[df['member_gender'] != 'Other']
```

```
my_palette = {'Subscriber': 'navy', 'Customer': 'deepskyblue'}

plt.figure(figsize = [10,7])
ax=sb.barplot(x = 'member_gender',y = 'dist_in_km', hue = 'user_type',
               palette = my_palette, data = df_ride_dist)
plt.title("Average Trip Distance by User Type", fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("User Type", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("Average Trip Distance(km)", fontsize=14)
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1));
```

It looks like this:

[Visualiztion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljqHt.jpg)

Can someone help me remove the other column completely from the visualization?

Comment: Can you to transform 'Other' into NaN ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using toy data (happy to share).   You could try to do the same, or post more code?

Comment: inside your ax.barplot(.....), insert data = df_ride_dist[df_ride_dist['member_gender']!= 'Other'], instead of data = df_ride_dist, this way your dataframe won't contain a column with the value 'Other'.  I think this should work

Comment: @Sy Ker could you tell me how can I do so?

Comment: @Tom can you tell me what code do you exactly want?

Comment: Ideal would be a singular block of code including some of your data (like 10 rows) which creates the issue; something that we could copy and paste and run.  If you can create this, it will be easier to diagnosis, and if you find you can't produce such an example it might point out what's different in your original code.  Your code posted so far looks like it should work, and using the same logic works for me, so it's possible some piece of information is missing

Comment: I converted the values to NaN and now it works. Thanks for your help everyone